Filtering Pandas DataFrame by Substring Match at Start of Strings
Trying to filter out rows in which the data of specific column start with a given substring.
I have a pandas.DataFrame as shown below (simplified):



price
DRUG_CODE




123
A12D958


234
B564F3C


...
...



I'm trying to filter out rows in which the DRUG_CODE does not start with the substring B21. However, most of the articles I found online about filtering DataFrames using substrings focus on identifying those that contain the substring, allowing it to appear anywhere within the cell (at the beginning, middle, or end)(eg: .str.contains() method). This doesn't align with my current requirement.

out = df[df['DRUG_CODE'].str.startswith('B21')]

out = df[~df['DRUG_CODE'].str.startswith('B21')] to inverse the logic

@mozway thank you so much for your help. As a complete beginner in python, your answer is very helpful and has pointed me in the direction for further learning :)

You can simply do this:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'price': [123, 234, 345],
    'DRUG_CODE': ['A12D958', 'B564F3C', 'B21X456']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

filtered_df = df[~df['DRUG_CODE'].str.startswith('B21')]

print(filtered_df)


filtered_df_with = df[df['DRUG_CODE'].str.startswith('B21')]

print(filtered_df_with)

which gives
   price DRUG_CODE
0    123   A12D958
1    234   B564F3C
   price DRUG_CODE
2    345   B21X456

